# why using the another way to declare the array can't work?

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image){
            $a=explode('/',$_image->getPath());
            $b=explode('-',$a[count($a)-1]);
            $colors[]=$b[1];                
        }
```

why i can't change `$colors[]=$b[1];`  to `$colors=$b[1];` . but `$color=array_unique($colors);` this is ok. $color it doesn't has `[]` ($color[])

Comment: You can change `$colors[]=$b[1]` to `$colors=$b[1]`. The former appends an entry to the `$colors` array, the latter overwrites the `$colors` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`array_unique()` returns an array, so if you assign that to another variable (`$colors`), that variable will be an array, too.

`$b[1]` gives only one element of an array - assign that to another variable and you will get a "simple" variable, not an array. to get an array in this case, you'll have to add the value as a entry to `$colors` (by writing `[]` and thus making it an array again).

Answer (score 0):

`$a []= $b` means "append `$b` to the array `$a`".

`$a = $b` means "set `$a` to refer to `$b`".

---

To more directly answer your question, you *can* say `$colors = $b[1]`, but that means "let `$colors` refer to the element at the index `1` in `$b`", and *not* "add the element at the index `1` in `$b` to the array `$colors`".

`array_unique` returns the unique values as an array.  So you will be assigning the array of unique values to `$colors`.